# In Delphi how to have a class that implements IComparable and inherits from TEqualityComparer?

Tags: delphi, dictionary

To explain my question I'll use something very similar to the `TDictionary` [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi)) in Embarcadero's website, but my class implements `IComparable`.

In Delphi (XE7):

```
TCity = class(TInterfacedObject, IComparable)
  Country: String;
  Latitude: Double;
  Longitude: Double;

  function CompareTo(Obj: TObject): Integer;
end;
```

I want a `TDictionary` with cities as keys:

```
Dictionary := TDictionary<TCity, string>.Create;

CityA := TCity.Create;
CityA.Country := 'United Kingdom';
CityA.Latitude := 51.5;
CityA.Longitude := -0.17;
Dictionary.Add(CityA, 'London');
```

Now, if I create a new city with the same values as before where `CityA.CompareTo(CityB)` returns `0`, like:

```
CityB := TCity.Create;
CityB.Country := 'United Kingdom';
CityB.Latitude := 51.5;
CityB.Longitude := -0.17;
```

And before adding `CityB` to the dictionary, I was expecting that:

```
Dictionary.ContainsKey(CityB)
```

would use my `CompareTo` implementation and `ContainsKey` would return `True`, but that is not the case. It seems that my class will also need to inherit from `TEqualityComparer`.

So how do I add an equality comparer—used by `ContainsKey`—to my class, additional to the `CompareTo` already there?

I know I could use a `TDelegatedEqualityComparer` and anonymous methods to create a custom comparer to be used when creating the dictionary. Something like:

```
Dictionary := TDictionary<TCity, string>.Create(CityComparer)
```

But is there a way to include the equality comparer in `TCity`, so that I don't need to have one when creating the dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing two things here. `IComparable` is meant for sorting.

`IEqualityComparer<T>` is to check if two items are equal or not but it also has the `GetHashCode` method that the dictionary is using internally.

For objects the default implementation for the `IEqualityComparer<T>` uses the virtual `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods from TObject. So if you want to treat two different instances as equal you have two options:

1. override these two methods in your class
2. provide a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: You are right. I realised, after trying it, that `IComparable` wouldn't be used in `ContainsKey`. But I need `IComparable`, so that's why I was asking on how to implement `IComparable`, and inherit from `TEqualityComparer`.What didn't occur to me is that I can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` without inheriting from `TEqualityComparer`—those methods are already part of `TObject`. So your option 1 did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. If you don't provide  an IEqualityComparer in then constructor TDictionary wil use the default one for the key.

Look in the constructor :

```
constructor TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Create(ACapacity: Integer; const AComparer: IEqualityComparer<TKey>);
var
  cap: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create;
  if ACapacity < 0 then
    raise EArgumentOutOfRangeException.CreateRes(@SArgumentOutOfRange);
  FComparer := AComparer;
  if FComparer = nil then
    FComparer := TEqualityComparer<TKey>.Default; // <-- HERE!
  SetCapacity(ACapacity);
end;
```

Her here in `GetBucketIndex` it is used

```
    function TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.GetBucketIndex(const Key: TKey; HashCode: Integer): Integer;
begin    
 ...
        // Found: return location.
        if (hc = HashCode) and FComparer.Equals(FItems[Result].Key, Key) then
...
end;
```

So no, you'll have to give the `IComparable` in the constructor

Comment: If you look at the actual implementation of `TEqualityComparer<T>.Default`, it checks if `T` (which would be `TCity` in this case) implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` and if so then returns a pointer to that implementation, thus `TDictionary<TCity>` can use `TCity`'s implementation of `IEqualityComparer<TCity>`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did not see anything (XE8), where there is a lookup to an implemented interface. But I see some routing to `Equals_Class` and `GetHashCode_Class` (with a nice default hash value 42). The default equality comparer will use the methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` from the class

Comment: IOW, no need to implement and pass in `IEqualityComparer<TCity>`, just override `TCity.Equals`.

Comment: Thank you @RudyVelthuis, it is exactly what I ended up doing. It didn't occur to me that I could simply override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` without the need to implement `IEqualityComparer`.